# Datatrigger with Storyboard not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, datatrigger

I have 5 different DataTriggers on the same Image, each for the same Binding but with a different Value, that each rotate the Image for a different angle.
After every change of the value, the value is reset to 0.

They worked for once when I did not add the `DataTrigger.ExitActions> <RemoveStoryboard>` thing, but they only worked once, so if the `steps` Binding got this value again, they would not fire.

```
<Image x:Name="drehteller" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="{Binding drehteller_image}">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding steps}" Value="1">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard1Step">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" 
                                        By="72"
                                        Duration="00:00:00:03"
                                    />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1Step"/>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding steps}" Value="2">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard2Step">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" 
                                        By="144"
                                        Duration="00:00:00:03"
                                    />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard2Step"/>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding steps}" Value="3">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard3Step">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" 
                                        By="216"
                                        Duration="00:00:00:03"
                                    />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard3Step"/>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding steps}" Value="4">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard4Step">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" 
                                        By="72"
                                        Duration="00:00:00:03"
                                    />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard4Step"/>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding steps}" Value="5">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard5Step">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" 
                                        By="360"
                                        Duration="00:00:00:03"
                                    />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard5Step"/>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

Maybe somebody has an idea on what I am doing wrong, I thought the `RemoveStoryboard` might fix the problem that they only fire one, but it looks like they don't.

EDIT: Found out that without the `ExitActions` I can fire the Trigger with Value 1 as often as I want, as long the Value never gets higher than 1, so if I once fire the Trigger with Value 2, The Trigger with Value 1 won't work anymore and if I fire the Trigger with Value 3, the Trigger with Value 2 won't work anymore. And so on, guess you got the idea.

Comment: StopStoryboard instead of RemoveStoryboard?

Comment: This would be a lot easier implemented in code behind.

Comment: @Clemens but I am coding in MVVM and I am not allowed to use the code behind, but I need to use the VM

Comment: MVVM lets you use attached behaviors and attached properties. Something like this might work well in an attached behavior - that gives you all of the power of the codebehind, but in a more modular and re-usable way.

Comment: That's a common misconception. MVVM does not at all mean that your view can't have any code behind. You would of course still have the same view model with the `steps` property, but instead of data binding just manually attach a PropertyChanged event handler that starts the animation.

Comment: @canton7 if I use StopStoryboard nothing happens.

Comment: @Clemens I would've done that in code behind right from the beginning, because it just has impact on the view, but my boss said I shall do it in the VM

Comment: I believe you're trying to rotate by 72 degrees across 5 steps right? The By value should be 72 for all your StoryBoards, please also show how you increment your steps, your code seems fine from the get go.

Comment: @IvanJazz no, the By value is fine for what I want. Yes one step equals 72 degress, but the DataTrigger with the Value 5 is for making 5 steps at once. The code for the steps is: `public void OnEventHandler(DrehtellerMoved e)
    {
      steps = e.steps; 
      steps = 0;
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple and straighforward solution would be to run an animation in code behind:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel();

viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(viewModel.Steps))
    {
        drehteller.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(
            RotateTransform.AngleProperty,
            new DoubleAnimation
            {
                By = viewModel.Steps * 72,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
            });
    }
};

DataContext = viewModel;
```

This does not contradict with MVVM, since the view model still knows nothing about the view. It's a pure view aspect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using an [attached behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726531(v%3Dexpression.40)). These are bits of reusable view logic which you can attach to various UI elements, without putting them in the codebehind.

You'll need the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf) (this used to be distributed as part of the "Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET" component for Visual Studio, but this changed in VS 2019).

Define your behavior. Note that `AssociatedObject` refers to the `Image` to which this behavior is associated, see below.

```
public class AnimateBehavior : Behavior<Image>
{
    public int Steps
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(StepsProperty);
        set => SetValue(StepsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StepsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Steps), typeof(int), typeof(AnimateBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0, (d, e) => ((AnimateBehavior)d).StepsChanged(e)));

    private void StepsChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject == null)
            return;

        AssociatedObject.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(
            RotateTransform.AngleProperty,
            new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                By = (int)e.NewValue * 72,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
            });
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML, you'll need this namespace:

```
xmlns:behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Then:

```
<Image ...>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:AnimateBehavior Steps="{Binding steps}"/>
    </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Image>
```